# PHP check if filename is in use and then add number on upload

Tags: php, counter

I'm trying to make a "send email" form which uploads files to a folder before the email is sent. The path to the files are then shown in the email, but if the files DO exist i don't want them to be overwritten, but i want to have a number added.

I have composed this tiny code, but it doesn't work!

<strike>The error says:</strike>

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name_of_uploaded_file' (T_VARIABLE) in /customers/8/5/6/HOMEPAGE/httpd.www/php/mailtest2.php on line 49**

The script below now upload a file if the file does not exist. If the file does exist nothing happens. The script ends at it should.

The script have been modified to what caused it not to ad "_1" to filename and save file in folder. Now it saves the file in folder and comes up with error: **Error while copying the uploaded file**

Can someone please explain to me what i do wrong?

Now all code is shown to debug this:

```
<?php
//Uploaded file 1

//Settings
$max_allowed_file_size = 2000; // size in KB
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "pdf");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Upload folder
//name also used later on mail
$name = $_POST['name'];
$d = date('d.m.y');
$varfoldername = "../receivedfiles/$name$d/";
if(!is_dir($varfoldername)) {
mkdir($varfoldername , 0777 , true);
}
$upload_folder = $varfoldername;

//Get the uploaded file information
$name_of_uploaded_file =
    basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);


//Validations
//----- Check if files exists and adds _X to it -----
$original_name_of_file = pathinfo($name_of_uploaded_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension =  pathinfo($name_of_uploaded_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$FileCounter = 0;

while (file_exists($varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file)) {
     $FileCounter++;
     $name_of_uploaded_file = $original_name_of_file . '_' . $FileCounter . '.' . $extension;
}

//copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
$path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
$tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
{
  if(move_uploaded_file ( $tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file ))
  {
    die("Error while copying the uploaded file");
  }
}

//Validate size requirements
$size_of_uploaded_file =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
{
  die("Fejl: Filen er for stor");
}

//------ Validate the file extension -----
//get the file extension of the file
$type_of_uploaded_file =
    substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
    strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);
$allowed_ext = false;
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
{
  if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
  {
    $allowed_ext = true;
  }
}

if(!$allowed_ext)
{
  die("The uploaded file is not supported file type. \n Send venligst filer af følgende type: .implode(',',$allowed_extensions)");
}

$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$hesteid = $_POST['hesteid'];
$hestenavn = $_POST['hestenavn'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
$land = $_POST['land'];
$formcontent=" Fra: $company \n Navn: $name \n Adresse: $adress , $areacode \n Land: $land \n Telefon: $phone \n Ringes op: $call \n Type: $type \n Hoppens navn og ID: $hestenavn , $hesteid \n Besked: \n $message \n Vedhæftede filer: \n $path_of_uploaded_file";
$recipient = "simon@secret.dk";
$subject = "Besked fra hjemmesiden";
$mailheader = "Fra: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: thank_you.shtml');
?>
```

Comment: The line `while (file_exists($varfoldername$name_of_uploaded_file ))` will cause a parse error. I guess you mean `while (file_exists("$varfoldername$name_of_uploaded_file" ))`. But you don't say what errors you get, or what exactly "doesn't work". That information would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to put it in. I have updated the question with this info. Added the """ will not work as it stops on the phppage.

Comment: Maybe you need a `$varfoldername . '/' . $name_of_uploaded_file` - best is if you could give us a `var_dump` of these two variables.

Comment: Using my suggestion will remove the parse error. so will everyone else's suggestions. If this is your whole problem, then it's nothing to do with file uploads - just how php parses code.

Comment: @ChrisLear That could very well be. I'm kinda new to PHP and this is at my very top limit.

I have tried your suggestion and what it does is that it uploads the file (if the file doesn't exist) to the folder and stop working on the phppage. If the file exist nothing happens.

Comment: I think, in that case, that it might help to re-write the question with the actual (parseable) code that is running, removing the part about the parse error, and with an explanation of what "stop working on the phppage" means, and how that differs from "nothing happens".

Comment: Hi again

I just modified the question. Found two stupid bugs. Now the script runs without error but doesn't add "_1" to the filename.

Comment: `"$varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file"` should be either `"$varfoldername$name_of_uploaded_file"` or `$varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file`

Comment: I'm getting confused. Neither of the three works but does only the exact same?

Comment: @SimonJensen I have added the complete code block to my answer. Hopefully that should sort you out :)

Comment: @SimonJensen what is the error?

Comment: I would always recommend using PHPMailer over `mail` , every time. `mail` is very exacting in its requirements and headers are very hard to get right. White space and everything in the headers is important, so far easier to [let PHPMailer build the email](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for you.

Comment: It says "Error while copying the uploaded file" which comes from this line of script:

  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
  {
    die("Error while copying the uploaded file");
  }
}

There is no fun in not doing it yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.` character to concatenate (stick together) different PHP variables, so:

```
while (file_exists($varfoldername$name_of_uploaded_file ))
```

will return you a parse error, because you need to tell PHP you want to string the two variables *together*, so instead use the `.` and write:

```
while (file_exists($varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file))
```

You may also need to add a `/` directory seperator between the two variables, but that's an issue not directly related to your current problem. But it's useful to `print $varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file` and see if it is the correct filepath layout (has all the `/` etc. )

## Further Work

> Hi again I just modified the question. Found two stupid bugs. Now the script runs without error but doesn't add "_1" to the filename. – Simon Jensen

Rearrange your code as such:

```
$FileCounter = 0;
$original_name_of_file = $name_of_uploaded_file;
while (file_exists($varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file)) {
     $FileCounter++;
     $name_of_uploaded_file = $original_name_of_file . '_' . $FileCounter . '.' . $extension;
}
```

What happened here:

- PHP in the while loop is overwriting the `$name_of_uploaded_file` so that if you have a `file_1.txt` then the next file name in the loop will be `file_1.txt_2.txt` and you can see this overwrite is far from perfect, instead you need to save the *Original* file, and then overwrite the original concatenated with the increment value and then the .txt .
- Your original value of `$name_of_uploaded_file` is not defined.
- `$FileCounter` for clarity is incremented before being written into the string.
- Your code of `$FileCounter++` will not work because you have defined `$FileCounter` as a **`string`** by setting it in quote marks. I have removed the quotes so it is now identified by PHP as an integer.
- Your `file_exists` call *should **not*** be in quotes as this is causing PHP extra, and needless work, and also will often confuse you as well as your IDE. The quotes in effect do:

> PHP Logic: I found a quote, I will start a string structure, oh, this
>   part looks like a variable, I will stop the string structure, then
>   concatenate this variable value into the string strucuture, then
>   continue the string, oh, another variable, I will stop the string
>   structure, and then concatenate the second variable into this string,
>   then continue. I found another quote so string finished.

Which is a far larger load of work than clearly and concisely defining two variables concatenated with a `.` .

## Complete Code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$d = date('d.m.y');
/***
Ideally folders should NEVER be relative, always base them from the PHP server 
root such as (example only), using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']:
$varfoldername = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/uploads/receivedfiles/".$name.$d."/";
***/
$varfoldername = "../receivedfiles/".$name.$d."/";
$upload_folder = $varfoldername;

$name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

$original_name_of_file = pathinfo($name_of_uploaded_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension =  pathinfo($name_of_uploaded_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$FileCounter = 0;

while (file_exists($varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file)) {
     $FileCounter++;
     $name_of_uploaded_file = $original_name_of_file . '_' . $FileCounter . '.' . $extension;
}

/***
Now $name_of_uploaded_file will have the numerical appendage as needed.
***/

if(move_uploaded_file( $tmp_path , $varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file )){ 
      print "file uploaded!";
    }
```

**IMPORTANT**

Do not use  `copy`, instead use PHP [Move_upload_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) :

```
if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file)){ ...
```

Becomes

```
if(move_uploaded_file ( $tmp_path , $path_of_uploaded_file )){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion but it doens't upload a file with "_1" if a file is allready present

Comment: Hi Martin. Wow! Thanks for the answer.. That explains a lot :) I have added how i define $name_of_uploaded_file to question.

Comment: @SimonJensen I have updated my answer, re viewing yuor question you have set the `$FileCounter` as a string and so the `$FileCounter++` action was probably failing as that only works on numeric values. Do these fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry. I'm getting quite confused now.

The total part of code is this:
**$original_name_of_file = pathinfo($name_of_uploaded_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$extension =  pathinfo($name_of_uploaded_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$FileCounter = 0;

while (file_exists($varfoldername.$name_of_uploaded_file)) {

     $FileCounter++;

     $name_of_uploaded_file = $original_name_of_file . '_' . $FileCounter . '.' . $extension;´**

Comment: Code in comments is very hard to read, add it as an **edit** at the bottom of your question and I'll take a look. Cheers

Comment: Thx a bunch! It now adds the file with the "_1" and "_2" but comes up with a failure. I have now all my email form code in question.

Comment: Awesome, @SimonJensen glad you got it sorted `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

There is not much need for using this long method when you could make a re-usable object out of it.

```
interface FileUploaderInterface
{
    public function upload($path);
}

class FileUploader implements FileUploaderInterface
{
    protected $File;
    public function __construct($file)
    {
          $this->File = $file;
          return $this;
    }
    public function upload($path)
    {
        if(file_exists($path.$this->File['name']))
        {
            $this->File["tmp_name"] = $this->File["name"] . '-' . time();
            move_uploaded_file($this->File, $path . $this->File["name"]);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($this->File, $path . $this->File["name"]);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can be used simply by using the `require_once()` and then this code:

```
$obj = new FileUploader($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
if(!$obj->upload(dirname(__FILE__) . '/example/path/ect')) {
    echo "File existed, we added the time onto the name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) says:

```
while (file_exists($varfoldername . $name_of_uploaded_file ))
```

Maybe you need a `$varfoldername . '/' . $name_of_uploaded_file` - best is if you could give us a *var_dump* of these two variables.

Comment: I have tried that but it stops working on the phppage on not moving on or give any errors.

Comment: That's why I asked for the value of these two variables. I guess you do not get any feedback, because the file does not exist. And the script works just fine ;)

Comment: `$name_of_uploaded_file_new` - what do you do with this variable? You could check if `file_exists($varfoldername . $name_of_uploaded_file )` is true. Since you do not get any error anymore, there must be a logical error but your code is fine.